# Updating current_user attribute to true from password update controller action

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, devise

My Rails 5 App only permits an admin or support user to create a user, when the user is created a password is generated and emailed to the user, on the first user login the app forces them to change the password.

I have a password_updated field in my schema that I want to be filled to true when the password is updated, however I am hitting a wall here, not sure if its coder eye and I just cant see what where im going wrong.

my application controller:

```
  # Force User To Change Password On First Login
  def after_sign_in_path_for(resource)
    if current_user.password_updated == "false"
      edit_passwords_path
    else
      authenticated_root_path
    end
  end
```

I have it set up so that if the user tries to skip or jump past the password change they are redirected to the password change.

my passwords controller:

```
class PasswordsController < ApplicationController
  def edit
    @user = current_user
  end

  def update
    if current_user.update_with_password(user_params)
      current_user.password_updated = "true"
      flash[:notice] = 'Your Password Has Been Sucessfully Updated.'
      redirect_to authenticated_root_path
    else
      flash[:error] = 'Oh No! Something Went Wrong, Please Try Again.'
      render :edit
    end
  end

  private
    def user_params
      params.require(:user).permit(:password_updated, :current_password, :password, :password_confirmation)
    end

end
```

Originally I had the application controller looking at the sign in count, however if the user closed out and waited long enough they could log back in and not have to change the password. I felt this was more of a risk.

Any assistance here would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: `password_updated` is boolean or string in DB?

Comment: @Aleksey it is a string, i can easliy change it to boolean if necessary

Comment: it is not necessary but it would be nice I think. just my advice =)

Comment: Ok i can change it, either way still not working lol..

Comment: I didn't it would work just by changing) now I am checking your code.

Comment: no worries, much appreciated.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/124143/discussion-between-aleksey-and-shawn-wilson).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the problem is that you don't save `current_user` after setting `password_updated` to true.
So the code should something like

```
def update
  update_params = user_params.merge(password_updated: true)
  if current_user.update_with_password(update_params)
    flash[:notice] = 'Your Password Has Been Successfully Updated.'
    redirect_to authenticated_root_path
  else
    flash[:error] = 'Oh No! Something Went Wrong, Please Try Again.'
    render :edit
  end
end
```

This way you would save `current_user` just once.

I suppose that `password_updated` is boolean field in DB.
Then in your `application_controller.rb` you can check it like `current_user.password_updated?`.

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest to allow admin create a user without a password. You will have to override the password_required method from devise.

```
def password_required?
   new_record? ? false : true
end
```

For a new record, when admin creates it, password is not required, but when the user signs up, it will prompt to add a password.
Or you can even keep condition like when the user is an admin, return false, else return true.

Comment: That would not allow the user to authenticate when setting a "real" password.

Answer (score 1):

I would choose a different approach using invitations.

Invited users are created with a token (a crypographically random string) which is used to identify the user. This removes the need to communicate the temporary password in clear-text and you can for example add expiry times to the invitation token for security.

So the app flow is the following:

- An admin visits `/invitiations/new`
- He fills in the form with the new users email and POSTs to `/invitations`
- An email is sent to the new user containing a link with an access token.
- The new user clicks the link and is sent to `/invitations/edit?invitation_token=ABCD12`
- The user fills in the form with a password, and sends a PATCH to `/invitations` with an invitation token in the request body.
- The user should then be prompted to sign with their new password.

A minimal example is:

```
class AddInvitationTokenToUser < ActiveRecord::Migration[5.0]
  def change
    add_column :users, :invitation_token, :string
    # this may not work on DBs that do not allow NULL on unique columns
    add_index :users, :invitation_token, unique: true
  end
end
```

Then we need to setup the User model to create random invitation tokens.

```
require 'securerandom'
class User < ApplicationRecord

  # @todo skip password validation if user has invitation_token

  def set_invitation_token!
    self.invitation_token = generate_invitation_token
  end

  private 

    def generate_invitation_token
      # this ensures that the token is unique
      begin
        token = SecureRandom.urlsafe_base64
      end while User.where(invitation_token: token).any?
      token
    end
end
```

Setup a controller for invitations:

```
class InvitationsController < ApplicationController

  before_action :authenticate!, only: [:new, :create]
  before_action :authorize!, only: [:new, :create]

  prepend_before_action :authenticate_user_from_token!, only: [:edit, :update]
  skip_before_action :authenticate!, :authorize!, only: [:edit, :update]

  def new
    @user = User.new
  end

  def create
    @user = User.new(create_params) do |u|
      u.set_invitation_token!
    end
    if @user.save
      # @todo email user invitation email
      redirect_to '/somewhere'
    else
      render :new
    end
  end

  def edit
  end

  def update
    if @user.update(update_params)
      @user.update_attibute(:invitation_token, nil)
      redirect_to new_session_path, notice: 'Please sign in.'
    else
      render :edit
    end
  end

  private

    def authenticate_user_from_token!
      unless params[:invitation_token].present?
        raise ActiveRecord::RecordNotFound and return 
      end 
      @user = User.find_by!(invitation_token: params[:invitation_token])
    end

    def create_params
      require(:user).permit(:email)
    end

    def update_params
      require(:user).permit(:password, :password_confirmation)
    end
end
```

There are several steps omitted here for brevity like skipping the password validation.

I would encourage you to check out [DeviseInvitable](https://github.com/scambra/devise_invitable) for a more complete example of this pattern.